# Node JS load jade over page

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a webpage; when a button is pressed, I want it to load a new Jade file. So the page doesn't change, but the display does.

The outcome is to have a static menu on the left but have the body of the page change, based on the button pressed.

I have this code for the buttons but I'm not sure how to continue. Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
this.newForm = function()
{
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/formBuilder',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'newForm'
        success: function (data){

        }
    });
}

this.openForm = function()
{
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/formBuilder',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'openForm'
    });
}

this.deleteForm = function()
{
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/formBuilder',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'deleteForm'
    });
 }
}
```